# gcc stack boundary

Tags: gcc, x86, elf, disassembly

I am aware that the stack boundary can be set using the `mpreferred-stack-boundary` argument to gcc. I was wondering if the following could be done.

1. On a particular machine find the default value used as the stack boundary.
2. For a particular compiled binary, is there any way I can figure out the value for stack boundary that was used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Difficult. It is probably the easiest thing to have a lookup table and update it when new architectures pop up.
2. Not really. The preferred stack boundary shows up in the values chosen for the stack pointer decrement in the function prologue of non-leaf functions, but there is no guarantee that this instruction takes any particular form or is emitted at all.